# How to change cordinate origin of raphael js paper

Tags: raphael

For 2d game purpose I have to set the origin (0,0) in a raphael js paper to another corner. By default origin is being set at the top left  corner of the paper. How can I change the origin position in raphael js so that elements can be drawn relative to the new origin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no official way.
You can transform all shapes ( width_of_canvas - shape_of_width ) / 2  and ( height_of_canvas - shape_of_height ) / 2 after creating. So you can crete them your origin and transform them with a function like this.

```
var paper = Raphael("canvas", 400, 400);
var offsetWidth = paper.width / 2,
offsetHeight = paper.height / 2;
var paperBorder = paper.rect(0,0,paper.width, paper.height).attr({ stroke:"black"})
var rectangle = paper.rect(0, 0, 50, 50).attr({
     stroke:"black",
     fill:"aqua"
})

function transformToCenter(shape) {
   var shapeProps = shape.getBBox();
   var itemOffsetWidth = offsetWidth - shapeProps.width / 2,
   itemOffsetHeight = offsetHeight - shapeProps.height / 2;
   shape.transform("t" + itemOffsetWidth + " " + itemOffsetHeight);
}
transformToCenter(rectangle);
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/XcsN/7zdeq5rt/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this.

Comment: My intention was to set the origin of the paper itself so that if I add new models it will position related to that. But seems there is no way other than draw everything and transform as you said. This is working fine thanks.